# Creating Shared Memory Segments

Tags: c

I have this struct in C:

```
struct first {
struct list *buf;   
struct pointers *ptr;  
};
```

A function to create a shared memory segment:

```
void * create_shared_memory(char *name, int size){

int *ptr;
int ret;


int fd = shm_open (name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

   if (fd == -1) { 
         perror ("shm_open error!");
     exit (1);
 }

ret = ftruncate (fd, sizeof (size));

   if (ret == -1) {
         perror ("ftruncate error!");
     exit (2);
 }

ptr = mmap(0, sizeof (size), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,  MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

   if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
         perror ("shm-mmap error!");
     exit (3);
 }
```

}

and a function to create a shared memory segment for that structure:

```
void shared_memory_structure(){

   create_shared_memory("struct", sizeof(struct first));

}
```

However I get an error. I found the problem was that the pointers inside the structure are not being pointed to the shared memory segment I just created. How can I do this ?

Comment: first of all, you never return in `create_shared_memory`. second, why are you mixing posix and linux interfaces? `mmap` can alloc anonymous shared pages.

Comment: the create_shared_memory is not supposed to return anything. it's job is to create a shared memory segment, and that's it @HuStmpHrrr

Comment: are you sure? do you know what this `void * create_shared_memory(char *name, int size)` mean? it's surprising you compiled this code section.

Comment: it's possible some of this is wrong, can you show me how to do it properly? @HuStmpHrrr

Comment: i have to confess i never use `shm_open`, but i think i read about it before, and it's consistent with kernel, which means it would be vanished with process. think about whether this is what you want? if not, mmap is enough, it's way easier to manage, and you need `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag. finally, return the pointer out. http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

Comment: Can you show me in an answer ? @HuStmpHrrr

Comment: you need to specify what you want from shared memory first. it's hard to configure with no info.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you are *trying* to do, but any time I see people putting structures containing pointers into shared memory alarms go off.  Two processes using the same shared memory won't necessarily have that shared memory at the same virtual address.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr i want to put that struture into a shared segment, so it can be shared with multiple processes

Comment: are they unrelated or forked?

Comment: ah... i saw a subtle error in your code. it should be `ftruncate (fd, size)` and `mmap(0, size, ...)`. try again.

Comment: they are all forked @HuStmpHrrr

Comment: still not working @HuStmpHrrr, i think the pointers aren't pointing to the shared memory, but i don't know how to do that

Comment: any error? how could you tell they are not working? more info please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out this code first. it's a demo code taken from http://blog.csdn.net/liuzhanchen1987/article/details/7455208 , which is in **Chinese**:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[4];
    int age;
}people;

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    people *p_map;
    char temp;
    p_map=(people*)mmap(NULL,sizeof(people)*10,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        sleep(2);
        for(i = 0;i<5;i++)
            printf("child read: the %d people's age is %d\n",i+1,(*(p_map+i)).age);
        (*p_map).age = 100;
        munmap(p_map,sizeof(people)*10);
        exit();
    }
    temp = 'a';
    for(i = 0;i<5;i++)
    {
        temp += 1;
        memcpy((*(p_map+i)).name, &temp,2);
        (*(p_map+i)).age=20+i;
    }
    sleep(5);
    printf( "parent read: the first people,s age is %d\n",(*p_map).age );
    printf("umap\n");
    munmap( p_map,sizeof(people)*10 );
    printf( "umap ok\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

expected result:

```
child read: the 1 people's age is 20
child read: the 2 people's age is 21
child read: the 3 people's age is 22
child read: the 4 people's age is 23
child read: the 5 people's age is 24
parent read: the first people,s age is 100
umap
umap ok
```

in which

```
mmap(NULL,size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
```

is **all** what you need to do before forking(and its return value checking code), and its return value will be the allocated pages starting address(if it's valid).

if all processes are forked. it's very handy to just use mmap to allocate anonymous pages, and additionally, there is no side effect after the processes get collected.

if you use `shm_open`, then in somewhere there will be a share memory object gets created, and it will be the side effect remains in your system, even after all your processes get collected. however, it's necessary when you plan to have two irrelevant processes talk to each other.